# How to create and commit a branch in gitlab

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04

This is intended as a question that I answer for other people's benefit. However, if someone answers this question before I finish my research, I would be grateful.

How do I, from the shell, branch an existing git repo (which I have developer access to), edit it, commit those changes then *push* it to the server for review before being merged.

**EDIT**

Please note that this is not my project, but someone else's. This use has given me access to do some work. When done, I will request that they merge the changes back to the original

Comment: hey mind accepting the answer for this on?

Answer (score 27):

For setting up your repo, you will need to follow [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#platform-linux). Then you will need to clone/fork the existing repo [like this](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

Then make your changes.  Once you are done making your changes.  You will need to make a "commit" that looks like this

```
git commit -m "I changed something somewhere"
```

Then you will want to pull down any changes from the repo that may have been pushed while you were working.

```
git pull origin master   // master being the branch that you cloned/forked
```

Once the pull is completed with no conflicts, you may push your changes up.

```
git push origin master   // this is saying that you want to replace the remote master branch with your local master branch
```

**EDIT**
To push to a repo without overwriting the master, do this:

```
git clone                   //clone what branch you want
git checkout -b new_branch  //this will create a new local branch
git push origin new_branch  //this will create a new origin branch
```

Comment: the problem is that I am not the Master of the repo, just the developer. I can fork/pull the git, but I can't commit the changes. From my understanding, I have to `branch` and then commit, and wait for approval and then a merge

Comment: Are you trying to push for your own records, or do you need to share with the developers of the current branch?

Comment: you will need to request permission to push to the repo.  Also you will need to rename the branch that you are on localy, so that when you push, you are not pushing ontop of the existing master.  I will update the answer.

Comment: do I rename it by issuing the command `mv sourcefolder destfolder` or through a git command? Also, do I request permission by calling the guy up and bribing him with beer or is there a git way of doing this?

Comment: You will want to rename the branch using git.  It is the "git checkout -b [new_branch_name]   //command above.  I would try pushing that branch up and see if that works, If not, try the beer... that should work.

Comment: What is the username? That is what everyone is not getting ... gitlab has some funny username schema ?

Comment: @mathtick this has nothing to do with username.  He is trying to create a Remote Branch to be reviewed before being pulled into the Remote Master branch.

Comment: @SariRahal you need username too. The complete answer is the one true answer. 

Username is on the settings and it not clear to those who sign up without creating a username. The main problem with this post above is that it probably has nothing to do with gitlab. If so then delete the whole thing and close.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly:

- You don't have permission to push to the repository
- You want to create a branch, make some commits, and then propose a merge request

This is actually a perfectly normal situation, here's what to do:

1. On GitLab, fork the project: this creates a clone of the original repository in your personal workspace. The point is that you can push to your personal workspace.
2. On your PC, clone from your fork, not the original.
3. Create a branch (`git checkout -b myfeature`), make the changes and commit, then push this branch to your fork (`git push -u origin HEAD`)
4. On GitLab, visit your fork's page, and near the top there should be a button offering you to create a Merge Request from the branch that you pushed just now. Click on it, review the changes, if it looks good, then set an assignee and click Create. The assignee should receive an email notification

You don't need write access to a project to be able to contribute.
All your write operations are on your workspace on GitLab and on your local PC.
Reviewers of your Merge Request can accept it or reject as they wish.
They can also ask that you make improvements, which you can implement and push (simple `git push` after your local commits), that updates the merge request (reviewers can reload the page in the browser and see your changes).